# Shortest unique presentable filepath - for each path in a list of paths

Tags: c#, algorithm

I have a console program where I want to present a list of input files as a prefix for the actual logic that the program calculates, for each file.

**Example to show the problem:**

Let's say that the program is going to show the last line of each file (`last_line.exe`), prefixed by the filename. I want the output to be the "star" of the output, so the filename should take up as little space as possible. But, it should be unique. And - the content part from each file should be aligned.

Showing the full path will make the prefix really long, and would not be aligned:

```
> last_line.exe C:\path\to\a\file.txt D:\another\path\to\a\file.txt
```

=>

```
C:\path\to\a\file.txt: "Here is the Last line of text in file.txt"
D:\another\path\to\a\file.txt: "And here is the last line of text in file.txt"
```

Not aligned and takes up more space than necessary.

The naive approach is to just truncate on the left side to a max width, i.e. 10 chars:

```
a\file.ext: "Here is the Last line of text in file.txt"
a\file.ext: "And here is the last line of text in file.txt"
```

These use less space and are aligned. The are however indistinguishable from each other.

---

**Wanted output:**

There certainly are multiple strategies on solutions to this. Here is a sample that I could live with-based on the above run of the program:

```
C:\...\file.txt: "Here is the Last line of text in file.txt"
D:\...\file.txt: "And here is the last line of text in file.txt"
```

---

I started implementing the above solution, but there are also other scenarios that are not that simplistic. What if the start is the same, but they differ with a folder in the middle, and they end the same? And, the list of files that are passed to the program is not limited to 2. It could be any arbitrary number of input files.

Which got me thinking that someone before me has had the same problem. Any suggestions on how to approach the problem?

The algorithm is needed for a .Net Core project made in C#, but I am interested in algorithms for other languages too.

Comment: To clarify the requirement: you're looking for a method which transforms strings using the above algorithm favoring the right most part of the path?  An example would help me, e.g. say you had path "@"C:\Users\Simon\Desktop\Newtonsoft.Json.dll", and you wanted to display 40 characters, what path would you want to display in this scenario?

Comment: I don't want to shorten just one path. As in the sample above, there are more than one path. So how can I display as little of the filename as possible without them getting non-unique. If I set the longest path to i.e. 10 characters, and showed just that, then all file-paths that were equal would seem like the same file in the output. I'll update the question to show an example of this.

Comment: BTW: I have been thinking that I could compare each character, from the right, and register which of the characters are the same. Then in sequences/ranges where the characters are the same, and the sequence is longer than 3 characters, then replace these with an ellipsis. Unless the characters are in the last 10, which should stay untouched.

Comment: Do you need to keep the whole filename, or do you care i.e. should the filename always be displayed?

Comment: It could be cut off, but the right-part is perhaps the most important user-information in regards to understanding what file it is. My approach so far on this has been to set a min-widht at i.e. 10 characters, that will always be shown.

Comment: Assuming all filenames are the same, what part of the path if preferred - left or right?

Comment: Right is *normally* the most important. But, there are scenarios that are more difficult. If i.e. the two argument files are at the same path, except for different drives. `c:\a\very\long\path\file.txt` `d:\a\very\long\path\file.txt`. For this scenario, the "right" result *could* be `c:\a...\file.txt` and `d:\a...\file.txt`. A difficult scenario though is if the third file argument is totally different: `c:\a\very\long\path\file.txt` `d:\a\very\long\path\file.txt` `c:\an\even\longer\path\file.txt` 
=> 
`c:\a\...\file.txt` and `d:\a\...\file.txt` `c:\an...\file.txt`
- Tricky stuff...

Comment: I was thinking along similar lines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are some extensions I use in my answer:

```
public static class IEnumerableExt {
    public static T MinByOrDefault<T, TKey>(this IEnumerable<T> src, Func<T, TKey> keySelector, T defval) => src.Aggregate(defval, (a, b) => Comparer<TKey>.Default.Compare(keySelector(a), keySelector(b)) <= 0 ? a : b);
}

public static class StringExt {
    // Substrings
    public static string Left(this string s, int charCount) => s.Mid(0, charCount);
    public static string Mid(this string s, int startPos, int charCount) { // negative startPos => count from end; negative charCount => count from length
        startPos = (startPos < 0) ? Math.Max(0, s.Length + startPos) : Math.Min(startPos, s.Length);
        charCount += (charCount < 0) ? s.Length - startPos : 0;
        return s.Substring(startPos, Math.Min(s.Length - startPos, charCount));
    }
    public static string Right(this string s, int charCount) {
        var startPos = Math.Max(0, s.Length - charCount);
        return s.Substring(startPos, Math.Min(s.Length - startPos, charCount));
    }
}
```

Given that `paths` contains the full paths of each file, compute some statistics on the paths:

```
var pathsCount = paths.Count();
var maxLen = paths.Select(p => p.Count()).Max();
```

Then, use LINQ to run over the possible left character count + right character count combinations, going slightly over the middle. For each combination, combine the left and right substrings and see if it is enough for all paths to be unique. Take the combination with the smallest sum of left and right characters:

```
var differs = Enumerable.Range(0, (maxLen + 3) / 2).SelectMany(left => Enumerable.Range(0, (maxLen + 3) / 2).Select(right => (left, right, sum: left + right)))
    .Where(lrs => paths.Select(d => d.Left(lrs.left) + d.Right(lrs.right)).GroupBy(ps => ps).Count() == pathsCount)
    .MinByOrDefault(lr => lr.sum, (left: maxLen / 2 + 1, right: maxLen / 2 + 1, sum: maxLen + 2));
```

If the smallest sum is shorter than 10 characters, increase the right count to make the total at least ten:

```
if (differs.left + differs.right < 10) {
    var newRight = Math.Max(differs.right, 10-differs.left);
    differs = (differs.left, newRight, differs.left + newRight);
}
```

Finally, process the paths to produce the shortened paths:

```
var ans = Enumerable.Range(0, paths.Count)
                    .Select(n => {
                        var shortPath = paths[n].Length - differs.sum < 3;
                        return paths[n].Left(differs.left) + (shortPath ? "" : "...") + paths[n].Right(shortPath ? paths[n].Length-differs.left : differs.right);
                    })
                    .ToList();
```

Comment: I like the approach of this. I think perhaps it yields better suggestions, as in more readable and understandable. They might end up longer than mine though. But, I guess if they are too short to make sense then that is not good neither...
BTW: A colleague suggested an approach of looking at this like a file path issue, rather than just characters. As the use case *is* for paths. So, compare path-element by path-element instead. Again, might produce longer strings, but would be clear to understand. My algorithm would not necessarily be suited for that. Yours is probably closer.

Comment: @Spiralis My first attempt actually did that, and preserved the filename independent of shortening, but it yielded long results. Of course, it didn't use my idea of trying all combinations, it just started at the left and right and found a set that were unique. Doing all might work fine. Including the filename in the shortening resulted in paths without the filename showing.

Answer (score 0):

I have worked a little on this, and while not perfect this is a start.
It has a limited number of tests, and no tests with more than 2 strings(!). So, that needs more work obviously. And, it has not been applied for real use in any program - yet.

But, I thought that I should share it at least. Maybe someone is able to spin on it and create something better.

BTW: The code is **not** optimized! Trying to get something that works at all first.

Implementation of the method that does the job:

```
/// <summary>
///     Shortens each string to become as short as possible, while keeping each entry unique.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="paths">The list of input paths</param>
/// <param name="fromRight">Whether the comparison is to be done from the left or right side.</param>
/// <param name="forceKeep">
///     Number of characters to not compare during comparison. This is always according to the
///     fromRight value. If fromRight, then forceKeep will keep the X rightmost characters in the result, even if they are
///     equal.
/// </param>
/// <param name="padChar">
///     The character to use for padding. If fromRight is true, then padding is on the left - and vice
///     versa
/// </param>
/// <param name="truncChar">The character to use as a truncation character.</param>
/// <param name="deltaContext">How many characters around a difference to keep to show context (5 means 2 before and 2 after)</param>
/// <returns>A tuple with the Result list of paths, plus a boolean Success indicator</returns>
public static (List<string> Result, bool Success) AbbreviatedUniquePath(IReadOnlyList<string> paths, bool fromRight = true, int forceKeep = 10, char padChar = ' ', char truncChar = '…', int deltaContext = 5)
{
    var largestInputLength = paths.Max(s => s.Length);

    forceKeep = Math.Min(forceKeep, largestInputLength);

    var fillChar = '▢';
    var paddedInput = (fromRight
            ? paths.Select(s => s.PadLeft(largestInputLength, fillChar))
            : paths.Select(s => s.PadRight(largestInputLength, fillChar))
        ).ToList();

    var forceKeepList = (forceKeep > 0
            ? fromRight
                ? paddedInput.Select(s => s.Substring(largestInputLength - forceKeep))
                : paddedInput.Select(s => s.Substring(0, forceKeep))
            : Enumerable.Repeat("", paths.Count)
        ).ToList();

    if (forceKeep > 0 && forceKeepList.Distinct().Count() == paths.Count)
    {
        // The forcePartList itself is enough to distinguish the input paths
        if (forceKeep < largestInputLength)
        {
            var result = forceKeepList.Select(f => $"{truncChar}{f}");
            // Found result in the "keep" area
            return (result.ToList(), true);
        }

        // Found result in the "keep" area
        return (forceKeepList, true);
    }

    var equalityMap = Enumerable.Repeat(0, largestInputLength - forceKeep).ToArray();
    var i = 0;
    while (i < largestInputLength - forceKeep)
    {
        var j = fromRight ? largestInputLength - forceKeep - i - 1 : i;
        var chars = paddedInput.Select(s => s[j]);
        equalityMap[j] = chars.Distinct().Count();
        i++;
    }

    var equalityMapList = equalityMap.ToList();

    // Find sorted distinct equality-levels
    var sortedEqualityMap = equalityMap.Distinct().ToList();
    sortedEqualityMap.Sort();
    sortedEqualityMap.Reverse();

    // Start with trying to replace use the most different characters only
    var testedResults = new List<string>(paths.Count);
    testedResults.AddRange(Enumerable.Repeat(new string('▢', largestInputLength - forceKeep), paths.Count));
    foreach (var eqLevel in sortedEqualityMap)
    {
        var eqLevelPos = largestInputLength - forceKeep - 1;
        do
        {
            eqLevelPos = equalityMapList.FindLastIndex(eqLevelPos, e => e == eqLevel);
            for (var index = 0; index < testedResults.Count; index++)
                // Special treatment for path-dividers
                if (new[] {'/', '\\'}.Contains(paddedInput[index][eqLevelPos]))
                {
                    // Insert at least two chars before and after to get context
                    var start = Math.Max(0, eqLevelPos - deltaContext / 2);
                    var length = Math.Min(paddedInput[index].Length - forceKeep, deltaContext);
                    var toInsert = paddedInput[index].Substring(start, length);
                    var before = testedResults[index].Substring(0, start);
                    var after = testedResults[index].Substring(start + length);
                    testedResults[index] = $"{before}{toInsert}{after}";
                    eqLevelPos = start;
                }
                else
                {
                    var tmpCharArray = testedResults[index].ToCharArray();
                    tmpCharArray[eqLevelPos] = paddedInput[index][eqLevelPos];
                    testedResults[index] = new string(tmpCharArray);
                }

            // Test if all strings are now different
            if (eqLevel == paths.Count || testedResults.Distinct().Count() == paths.Count)
            {
                // All are different
                for (var k = 0; k < paddedInput.Count; k++)
                    // Append the forceKeepList strings
                    testedResults[k] = $"{testedResults[k]}{forceKeepList[k]}";

                var abbreviatedResults = testedResults.Select(t =>
                {
                    var regex = new Regex($"{fillChar}+");
                    var result = regex.Replace(t, truncChar.ToString());
                    return result;
                }).ToList();

                var longestPaddedResult = abbreviatedResults.Max(t => t.Length);

                var paddedResults = (fromRight
                        ? abbreviatedResults.Select(s => s.PadLeft(longestPaddedResult, padChar))
                        : abbreviatedResults.Select(s => s.PadRight(longestPaddedResult, padChar))
                    ).ToList();
                // The generated results are fine to return (probably)
                return (paddedResults, true);
            }
        } while (eqLevelPos >= 0);
    }

    // Did not find a way to differentiate all string.
    return (testedResults, false);
}
```

And the (NUnit) tests to "verify" them:

```
[Test]
public void Find_ShortestUnique_Start_And_Length_Differ_Test()
{
    var input = new[]
    {
        "path/to/a/file.txt",
        "another/path/to/a/file.txt"
    };
    var expected = new[]
    {
        "      …a/file.txt", 
        "…er/pa…a/file.txt"
    };
    AssertShortestUniqueResults(input, expected);
}

[Test]
public void Find_ShortestUnique_Start_Differ_Test()
{
    var input = new[]
    {
        "/c/src/path/to/a/file.txt",
        "/d/src/path/to/a/file.txt"
    };
    var expected = new[]
    {
        "…c…a/file.txt", 
        "…d…a/file.txt"
    };
    AssertShortestUniqueResults(input, expected);
}

[Test]
public void Find_ShortestUnique_Start_Differ_Without_Skip_Test()
{
    var input = new[]
    {
        "/c/src/path/to/a/file.txt",
        "/d/src/path/to/a/file.txt"
    };
    var expected = new[]
    {
        "…c…a/file.txt", 
        "…d…a/file.txt"
    };
    AssertShortestUniqueResults(input, expected);
}

[Test]
public void Find_ShortestUnique_End_Differ_Test()
{
    var input = new[]
    {
        "/c/src/path/to/a/file.txt",
        "/c/src/path/to/a/file.dat"
    };
    var expected = new[]
    {
        "…a/file.txt", 
        "…a/file.dat"
    };
    AssertShortestUniqueResults(input, expected);
}

[Test]
public void Find_ShortestUnique_Middle_Differ_Test()
{
    var input = new[]
    {
        "/c/src/path/to/a/file.txt",
        "/c/src/path/to/b/file.txt"
    };
    var expected = new[]
    {
        "…a/file.txt", 
        "…b/file.txt"
    };
    AssertShortestUniqueResults(input, expected);
}

[Test]
public void Find_ShortestUnique_Start_And_End_Differ_Test()
{
    var input = new[]
    {
        "/c/src/path/to/a/file.txt",
        "/d/src/path/to/a/file.dat"
    };

    var expected = new[]
    {
        "…a/file.txt", 
        "…a/file.dat"  
    };
    AssertShortestUniqueResults(input, expected);
}

[Test]
public void Find_ShortestUnique_Start_Middle_And_End_Differ_Test()
{
    var input = new[]
    {
        "/c/src/path/to/a/file.txt",
        "/d/src/path/to/b/file.dat"
    };
    var expected = new[]
    {
        "…a/file.txt",
        "…b/file.dat"
    };
    AssertShortestUniqueResults(input, expected);
}

private static void AssertShortestUniqueResults(IReadOnlyList<string> input, IReadOnlyList<string> expected)
{
    var (actual, success) = AbbreviatedUniquePath(input);
    Assert.That(success, Is.EqualTo(true));
    Assert.That(actual.Count, Is.EqualTo(expected.Count));
    for (var i = 0; i < expected.Count; i++) Assert.That(actual[i], Is.EqualTo(expected[i]));
}
```